# How to change the value of a Array

Tags: java

I have writen a code like below-

```
public class ArrayExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = { 20, 50, 40, 8 };
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

output is: 20 50 40 8

Now i want to change the value of myArray.Now I want to set `myArray = {100,1,200,80};`

I have searched and tried but unable to do this.Please Java Experts need your help.

Comment: Did you search google with your doubt-simply `int[] myArray = { 100, 1,200,80 };` would have solved your purpose as achieved previously!!!

Comment: You know the elements, you have a `for` loop running and you know about accessing arrays using indexes. What else is difficult here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declare it with new values.

```
 int[] myArray = {100,1,200,80};
```

Comment: @NotSoOldNick-There is no need of `new int[]`!

Comment: @shekharsuman The new int[] is indeed necessary. `Array constants can only be used in initializers`

Comment: @Bryan-That's what I am saying.See,his answer as per the amended code,it's fine as he has initialized the array afresh. So,no new need of `new int[]`!

Comment: @shekharsuman read the question again, he's saying that he 'now want to change the value of the array', Bryan is right

Comment: @Bryan-I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: @eitanfar-Thanks for pointing out about the hurriedness!

Comment: @shekharsuman I also misunderstood your intention. Either way works. Just a difference between initializing and re-initializing.

Comment: So in other words, my initial answer before being edited was fine: you can either re-initialise the same variable using `myArray = new int[]{100,1,200,80};` or declare a new one using `int myNewArray = {100,1,200,80};`, or even use the solution provided by @Fahriyal Afif, which is equally correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray[0] = 100;
myArray[1] = 1;
myArray[2] = 200;
myArray[3] = 80;
```